# Where can i find react js with php mysql source code samples

Tags: reactjs

I am a PHP developer wanting to learn react js. However, I tried googling for samples codes that i can pick up but found none. All my database are in mysql. Seeking any advise on this?

Terry

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) will create a standard React project seed, you can look at the code it generates for a start.

Otherwise, the React tutorials on their official website is full of code examples.

Comment: Yes. But i cant seems to find react connects to mysql.https://www.codeofaninja.com/2016/07/react-crud-tutorial.html?utm_source=hashnode.com is not free.

Comment: Why do you want to use React in the first place? You don't seem to really know what it does.

Comment: Hi, I am looking into developing hybrid apps. Therefore, learning react and later into React Native may seems to be the better choice.

Comment: The main message is that React is for user interfaces, it has nothing to do with MySQL. All you can do is do standard Ajax calls from your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

> This site helped me when I learnt PHP, mySQL and implementing a react frontend, along with CRUD functionality, and seeing how the frontend adapts. I know you've asked this question a long time ago, so I hope you've come right, but here's my input for a coverage on
>
> - ReactJs introduction
> - React CRUD operations using PHP API and MySQL
>   Credits to : Durgesh Sahani

[DEVTO](https://dev.to/durgeshsahani/react-crud-operations-using-php-api-and-mysql-13da)